# What delegate method will be called on receiving a push notification if the app is in killed/Force closed (Not in background) state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am currently working on a project which needs to store the pushnotification details in the local storage whenever the notification received.

As of now i could able to receive and store the push notification when the app is in foreground and background.

But when the app is force closed, i couldn't able to store the notification, since on receiving the notification am not getting any trigger in the code,
if click on the notification in the notification panel then i am getting the trigger in the code.

i want and approach were i can save the notification with out touching the received notification even the app is in killed state.

Comment: `- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` You can confirm this by displaying UIAlertview in this method in `Appdelegate`

Comment: Hi Milan, Thanks for your response but this is getting called when the app is in background, but not getting executed if the app is force closed

Comment: @jaffer no method will get called .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never get any information about APNS when your app is killed.

Now how you will get detail about notification when app is killed and then you open the app. I had the same problem and here is my solution which I have applied to resolve it.

We have created one table called Notification detail.

When server fire any Push notification same time we saved that in that above table. And when app is launch we fetch all notification by used-id

We also save the last notification-id to manage the badge count.

Comment: but how can i saved this in table?

Answer (score 0):

You can able to receive the PushNotification When your app is not running by setting below configurations.

1. In your application's settings, Select target > Select Capabilities > Turn On Background Modes and Select Remote Notifications check box.
2. In your push notification payload, include the `"content-available:true"`.

Now you the iOS will launch your app automatically in background mode, once received a push message with `"content-available:true"`. So you can save your updates in below method.

`-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler`

Please refer this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) for more info from apple. Also refer this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1) as well.

Thanks!

Comment: your answer is not related to the question the questioner clearly mentioned not in background, but your answer is related to background mode can you modify the answer, but real answer is not possible

Comment: But the Question is related to this answer as he wants to receive the PushMessage when the app is closed/killed. So this will be the way to achieve his requirements.

Comment: no my bro, completionHandler only used for suspend and not running mode , not in terminate mode bro

Comment: @ Natarajan are you taking about this in document,Provide this key with a value of 1 to indicate that new content is available. Including this key and value means that when your app is launched in the background or resumed, application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is called.

Comment: This will work for app background not for killed state

Comment: Yes Jaffer, The app will be launched by iOS automatically and didReceiveRemoteNotification will be called as i told above, so there is no need of user action to launch the app.

Comment: i have implemented everything perfectly and i am receiving notifications too . but it never goes inside application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method unless user taps on notification message . do you have any solution regarding this ?

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   //Check here launchOptions.
    return YES;
}
```

this method will get called when you click on notification alert if the app is forced closed.
Check for `launchOptions`. If lauchOptions is not nil then notification is present and handle the notification accordingly. You can get the `userInfo` from `launchOptions`. `userInfo` contains all the infromation of push notification.

Comment: i want and approach were i can save the notification with out touching the received notification even the app is in killed state.

Comment: @jaffer you have to manage  notification information into your local database.